# How to disable a function when other function is called

Tags: vue.js, django-rest-framework

I'm trying to `enable|disable` this function on my VueJS thru toggle button. When the user click enable, axios will call the API endpoint of that function from django so means that `auto_sms` is up.

but when the user click disable, axios will call another API endpoint for disabling `auto_sms`. How can I do that? Thanks

like `if disable_auto() = True then auto_sms() will not execute automatically.`

@views.py

```
def auto_sms(request):
    responses = SampleData.objects.filter(
        level='High',
        created_gt=now() - timedelta(days=3),
        sms_sent=False,
    )
    if responses.count() >= 50:
        send_sms()
        responses.update(sms_sent=True)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can keep the loaders or disables. Something like:

```
<template>
  <div class="hello">
    <button :disabled="loaders.secondApiCall" @click="onFirstApiClick">
      first api call
    </button>
    <button :disabled="loaders.firstApiCall" @click="onSecondApiCall">
      second api call
    </button>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "HelloWorld",
  props: {
    msg: String,
  },
  data: () => ({
    loaders: {
      firstApiCall: false,
      secondApiCall: false,
    },
  }),
  methods: {
    onFirstApiClick() {
      this.loaders.firstApiCall = true;

      setTimeout(() => {
        this.loaders.firstApiCall = false;
      }, 1000);
    },
    onSecondApiCall() {
      this.loaders.secondApiCall = true;

      setTimeout(() => {
        this.loaders.secondApiCall = false;
      }, 1000);
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

You will disable one button when you call the other one. You can understand the whole idea which will apply to your case. [Codepen here](https://codesandbox.io/s/spring-mountain-mxvcl?file=/src/components/HelloWorld.vue)

Comment: Thank you! I will try this :)